# Table styling with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I made a simple HTML table for this question.

I want to have a different style for the text and a different one for the numbers in the `<td>` and in the `<tfoot>`.

Can I style text differently from numbers in `<td>` and the `<tfoot>`?

**and**

What is the best way in the web practice to style a more complex table?

**Update**

Like this?

```
<td> 12<b>x</b>6 </td>
```

[Here is my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PXg8X/39/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <caption>Woah</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Animalistic</th>
            <th>People</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <td>Run</td>
        <td>1 x 92</td>
        <td>1 x 92</td>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>9889 x 92</td>
            <td>9889 x 92</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bill</td>
            <td>9889 x 92</td>
            <td>9889 x 92</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width:300px;
    background:#f5f7f3;
}
caption {
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
th {
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:40px;
    background:#b2b2b2;
}
td {
    border:1px solid #b2b2b2;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML5 or CSS3. Just normal CSS and HTML will do.

Comment: You can target `tbody td` / `thead th` / `tfoot td` etc.

Comment: Well... If I have numbers and text in the `<td>`? How do I style them differently?

Comment: If they are both in the same `td` you can't without putting them in another HTML element. Or you could use http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-fonts-3-20131003/#unicode-range-desc

Comment: Like this `<td> 12<b>x</b>6 </td>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a < span > tag to the text with the style you want.

```
<td><span style="some style" or class = "some  class"> some text </span></td>
```

Comment: Thanks! HTML tag will do the different styling of text and numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set different color for numeric value and text if they are in same tag. You have to give them separate tag. Like:

```
<td><span>1</span> text <span>92</span></td>
```

Then add css:

```
td span{
    color:red;
}
```

> **Note:** numeric values are in span tag and text value don't have any
>   tag. so with this css we can set color for numeric value and text
>   value different

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to target table elements. [Here is an excellent list of available CSS selectors.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

[Example of the below](http://jsbin.com/guhixu/1/edit).

Basic HTML structure (only one `<tbody>`):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>9999 x 9999</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
       <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

To target the numbers separately, use a `<span>`:

```
<td>9999 <span>x</span> 9999</td>
```

OR

```
<td><span>9999</span> x <span>9999</span></td>
```

Target in the CSS with:

```
tbody td span {
  /* styles */
}
```

Target every second row in the tbody with `nth-child`:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(even) { 
    background: #F00; 
}
```

Target every td in the tbody:

```
tbody td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Target the first td of each row:

```
tbody td:first-child {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Target the tfoot itself

```
tfoot {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I was asking about styling a text and a number in one cell.

Comment: Sorry :P! I will remember that!